# How to set the Shift + End to select to the end of line?

Tags: macos, monodevelop, key-bindings

I'm using MonoDevelop 2.6 on MacOS X Snow Leopard.

Is there a way to customize the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>END</kbd> (and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>) key combinations  to select only to the end (or beginning) of the current line, not to the end of the document?

I suppose there is an option somwhere in MonoDevelop for customizing the cursor position after an <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Home</kbd> key (choosing between `EoL` or `EoF`), but I cannot find it in the keyboard settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how the Home and End keys work in MacOS. To expand the selection to the line start/end on MacOS, you would use Shift-Command-Left/Right. Most Mac apps (including MD) also respect the emacs commands Shift-Control-a/e.

If you want a Windows-like behaviour, look for the commands "Expand selection to line start" and "Expand selection to line end" in MonoDevelop's Key Bindings preferences and remap them.

Comment: Thank you! I've also found an utility to set key bindings for all Mac applications: http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/

Comment: BetterTouchTool was also able to do this for me (edit system wide).  I can't believe this is the default and it hasn't bothered me until this point.